# Self-Deleting Viewmodel in detail view - Bad Practise?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, mvvm, viewmodel

I have a master-detail application in which the detail viewmodel/view has the capability to perform the delete command.

But how can I inform the master-collection in the master-viewmodel that the detail-viewmodel is deleted and had to removed from the collection?

Is this a bad design and the master-viewmodel has to delete the detail?
Or is the only option to do this via an event? MVVM conform?

Here a shortened code

**ViewModel**

```
public class AllMetalTransactionViewModel : WorkspaceViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<MetalTransactionViewModel> _metalTransactions;
    public ObservableCollection<MetalTransactionViewModel> MetalTransactions
    {
        get { return _metalTransactions; }
        set
        {
            if (Set("MetalTransactions", ref _metalTransactions, value))
            {

            }
        }
    }

    private MetalTransactionViewModel _selectedMetalTransaction;
    public MetalTransactionViewModel SelectedMetalTransaction
    {
        get { return _selectedMetalTransaction; }
        set
        {
            if (Set("SelectedMetalTransaction", ref _selectedMetalTransaction, value))
            {

            }
        }
    }
}

public class MetalTransactionViewModel : WorkspaceViewModel
{
    private RelayCommand _deleteCommand;
    public RelayCommand DeleteCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _deleteCommand
                   ?? (_deleteCommand = new RelayCommand(
                        () =>
                            {
                                if (!IsNewUnit)
                                {
                                    _dataService.DeleteMetalTransaction(_metalTransaction, CallbackDelete);
                                    _dataService.CommitAllChanges(delegate(bool b, object o) {  });

                                    // How can I inform the AllMetalTransactionViewModel that I'm deleted? Event?
                                }
                            },
                        () => !IsNewUnit));
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML-Master**

```
<View:MetalTransactionView Grid.Column="1" 
DataContext="{Binding SelectedMetalTransaction}"></View:MetalTransactionView>
```

**XAML-Detail**

```
<Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
Padding="5" Content="Löschen" Margin="5" Width="80" 
Command="{Binding Path=DeleteCommand}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day to you!

You can do it in several ways (I like A and D solution):

**A.** The detail view model has a link to Master Detail View Model (some light interface with one method `void RemoveDetail(MetalTransactionViewModel detail)`) or Collection of Details View Models.
For example (there link to collection):

The Details View Model:

```
public class MetalTransactionViewModel : WorkspaceViewModel
{
    private RelayCommand _deleteCommand;

    IList<MetalTransactionViewModel> ParentCollection { get; }

public RelayCommand DeleteCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _deleteCommand
                   ?? (_deleteCommand = new RelayCommand(
                        () =>
                            {
                                if (!IsNewUnit)
                                {
                                    _dataService.DeleteMetalTransaction(_metalTransaction, CallbackDelete);
                                    _dataService.CommitAllChanges(delegate(bool b, object o) {  });

                                     if (ParentCollection == null) { return; }
if (ParentCollection.Contains(this)) { ParentCollection.Remove(this); }
                                }
                            },
                        () => !IsNewUnit));
        }
    }

}
```

In Main View Model, when creating Detail View Model:

```
private MetalTransactionViewModel CreateDetailViewModel()
{
  return new MetalTransactionViewModel() { ParentCollection = MetalTransactions };
}
```

**B.** Use a event as you say (but **be careful**, because **it could bring to you a memory leak**). Please, review [WeakEventManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.weakeventmanager.aspx)

**C.** If you are using mvvm toolkit, such as a [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) you can use [Messenger](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/09/27/mvvm-light-toolkit-messenger-v2-beta.aspx) class to inform Master View Model of remove action.

**D. Move you Remove Command to the Main View Model. I suppose it's most good solution in this case. I believe the Main View Model must manipulate of Collection Details View Models**.

I hope it will help you!

Comment: Nice answer Daniil, vote up! @masterchris_99 I'd go with option D, after all the MasterVM should know about its details/childs (or slaves :-P)